# How to extend a method at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, aop, expandoobject

Here is the class:

```
class Foo
{
    private void Boo()
    {
        // Body...
    }

    // Other members...
}
```

What I need is:

- Create a `Foo2` class at runtime which has a copy of all `Foo` class members.
- In `Foo2` class replace `Boo` method by `Boo2` method that has its content alternated to some extent.
- Create an instance of `Foo2` and invoke `Boo2`.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Would it be possible to change the signature of Boo to `protected virtual`?

Comment: Could you explain why you are doing this? I get the feeling there is a better way...

Comment: @PMF Eventually yes - it could be possible to change the signature of Boo to `protected virtual`, however I'm actually looking for solution that will allow to not touch the original code.

Comment: Would partial methods solve your problem? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b0scde8.aspx

Comment: @RichardEv that was my initial thought as well, however, I would like to hear the justification first.

Comment: @James I'm writing a test that uses `Foo`. Test is finished when `Boo` is finished. I need to put some notification into `Boo` method in order to stop my test.

Comment: Yes you can do it,but it's little complicated. Check TypeBuilder class and example is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @RyszardDżegan extending behaviour is probably best served using AOP and there are [tools](http://www.postsharp.net/aop.net) out there for that. Partials wouldn't work in this case because you want to *extend* not implement the full method.

Comment: @RichardEv `Boo` is kind of spaghetti code. There is an `if` inside. My test is finished within that `if`. I don't want to do any refactoring of that method. Just make a copy of it, find that `if` inside that copy and attach some notification after that. The key thing here is to not amend original `Foo` nor `Boo`.

Comment: @RyszardDżegan: That usually calls for a refactored class. `Boo` and the calling method should be in different classes so you can mock boo the usual way. Alternatively make Boo `internal protected virtual` (assuming you have InternalsVisibleTo set for your test assembly) and create a derived class Foo2 in your test where you can override Boo.

Comment: @Selman22 That sounds good. Could you please add an example that meets my three points to give me a quick start point?

Comment: @James I know that with such tools I'm able to add actions to certain points within my method body. However, can I also have finer control over where I set such extensions?

Comment: i use it for create a new assembly and class at runtime for example,but you want copy a method body,i'm not sure i can do that,in microsoft example they emit CLR opcodes into method body,so to do this i guess you must have CLR knowledge or you can open your current assembly with ILDASM.exe and copy your method Opcodes and emit them with c# code.. as i said it's really complicated

Answer (score 1):

You can do it at runtime using a .NET AOP Framework event if it is not the the main purpose of this kind of framework.

I actively work on a new one which can handle it event if your method is not virtual.

You can take a look on [NConcern .NET runtime AOP Framework](http://aspectize.codeplex.com)

The monkey patch "aspect" :

```
public class MonkeyPatch : IAspect
{
    static public void Patch(MethodInfo oldMethod, MethodInfo newMethod)
    {
        //update monkey patch dictionary
        MonkeyPatch.m_Dictionary[oldMethod] = newMethod;

        //release previous monkey patch for target method.
        Aspect.Release<MonkeyPatch>(oldMethod);

        //weave monkey patch for target method.
        Aspect.Weave<MonkeyPatch>(oldMethod);
    }

    static private Dictionary<MethodInfo, MethodInfo> m_Dictionary = new Dictionary<MethodInfo, MethodInfo>();

    public IEnumerable<IAdvice> Advise(MethodInfo method)
    {
        if (MonkeyPatch.m_Dictionary.ContainsKey(_Method))
        {
            yield return Advice(MonkeyPatch.m_Dictionary[_Method]);
        }
    }
}
```

Patch :

```
static public void main(string[] args)
{
    //create Boo2, a dynamic method with Boo signature.
    var boo2 = new DynamicMethod("Boo2", typeof(void), new Type[] { typeof(Foo) }, typeof(Foo), true);
    var body = boo2.GetILGenerator();

    //Fill your ILGenerator...
    body.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    //Apply the patch
    MonkeyPatch.Patch(typeof(Foo).GetMethod("Boo"), boo2);
}
```

in the second hand, if you just need to call something after the original call, you are in AOP aim and you can do it like that...

Observation Aspect :

```
public class Observation : IAspect
{
    static public void Observe(MethodInfo method, Action action)
    {
        //update observation dictionary
        Observation.m_Dictionary[method] = action;

        //release observation aspect for target method
        Aspect.Release<Observation>(method);

        //weave observation aspect for target method.
        Aspect.Weave<Observation>(method);
    }

    static private Dictionary<MethodInfo, Action> m_Dictionary = new Dictionary<MethodInfo, Action>;

    public IEnumerable<IAdvice> Advice(MethodInfo method)
    {
        if (Observation.m_Dictionary.ContainsKey(method))
        {
            yield return Advice.Basic.After(Observation.m_Dictionary[method]);
        }
    }
}
```

Use case :

```
static public void main(string[] args)
{
    Observation.Observe(typeof(Foo).GetMethod("Boo"), () => { /* paste here your notification code... */ });
}
```